# Logic App workflow creating or updating documents in CosmosDB fails with conflict

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

I'm in the process of creating a Logic App which should copy all documents from specific containers in the database to a different database and its corresponding collections.

For this, I've created a workflow which retrieves all documents, loops through them and tries to do a Create or Update document on the target location.
As you can see on the image, this looks fairly straightforward.

[image: workflow steps of retrieving and updating documents]

I've specified the PartitionKey in the header and Upsert is set to `true`, so if a document already exists it'll be updated, otherwise created.
Originally, the body was filled with `@items('[blurred]_-_For_each_document')`.

However, I got an error stating there was a conflict on the id.

I've also tried to remove all 'system' properties like so:

```
@removeProperty(removeProperty(removeProperty(removeProperty(removeProperty(items('[blurred]_-_For_each_document'), 'id'), '_rid'), '_self'), '_ts'), '_etag')
```

but it appears not having an `id` in place isn't valid, so now I've got this as I'm only interested in having the contents of the 'actual' document:

```
@removeProperty(removeProperty(removeProperty(removeProperty(items('[blurred]_-_For_each_document'), '_rid'), '_self'), '_ts'), '_etag')
```

This still fails.

The raw input looks a bit like this:

```json
{
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
        "x-ms-documentdb-raw-partitionkey": "1050",
        "x-ms-documentdb-is-upsert": "True"
    },
    "path": "/dbs/[myDatabase]/colls/[myCollection]/docs",
    "host": {
        "connection": {
            "name": "/subscriptions/[subscriptionGuid]/resourceGroups/[resourcegroup]/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/[connectionName]"
        }
    },
    "body": {
        "id": "2faee185-4a51-4797-bff9-3ce23a603690",
        "MyPartitionKeyNumber": 1050,
        "SomeValue": false,
    }
}
```

With the following response:

```json
{
  "code": "Conflict",
  "message": "Entity with the specified id already exists in the system., ... ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Upsert ..."
}
```

I know for a fact, the `id` doesn't exist, but changed the step to do a `PUT` anyway.

```json
{
    "method": "put",
    "headers": {
        "x-ms-documentdb-raw-partitionkey": "1050",
        "x-ms-documentdb-is-upsert": "True"
    },
    "path": "/dbs/[myDatabase]/colls/[myCollection]/docs",
    "host": {
        "connection": {
            "name": "/subscriptions/[subscriptionGuid]/resourceGroups/[resourcegroup]/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/[connectionName]"
        }
    },
    "body": {
        "id": "2faee185-4a51-4797-bff9-3ce23a603690",
        "MyPartitionKeyNumber": 1050,
        "SomeValue": false,
      }
}
```

With a response I'm expecting to see:

```json
{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "message": "Resource not found"
}
```

I've also tried to do a `Delete document` before running the `Create or Update document` step, but got the same error(s).

There's some post here on Stack Overflow stating the `x-ms-documentdb-raw-partitionkey` should be `x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey` (without the `raw`-part), but doing so results in the following error message:

> PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header

For completeness sake, these are the relevant steps of my workflow:

```json
"[blurred]_-_Get_all_documents": {
    "type": "ApiConnection",
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['documentdb_3']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "method": "get",
        "path": "/v2/dbs/@{encodeURIComponent('myDatabase')}/colls/@{encodeURIComponent(items('[blurred]_-_For_each_collection'))}/docs"
    },
    "runAfter": {}
},
"[blurred]_-_For_each_document": {
    "type": "Foreach",
    "foreach": "@body('[blurred]_-_Get_all_documents')?['value']",
    "actions": {
        "[blurred]_-_Create_or_Update_document_on_blurred2": {
            "type": "ApiConnection",
            "inputs": {
                "host": {
                    "connection": {
                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['documentdb_4']['connectionId']"
                    }
                },
                "method": "post",
                "body": "@removeProperty(removeProperty(removeProperty(removeProperty(items('[blurred]_-_For_each_document'), '_rid'), '_self'), '_ts'), '_etag')",
                "headers": {
                    "x-ms-documentdb-raw-partitionkey": "@{items('[blurred]_-_For_each_document')['MyPartitionKeyNumber']}",
                    "x-ms-documentdb-is-upsert": true
                },
                "path": "/dbs/@{encodeURIComponent('myDatabase')}/colls/@{encodeURIComponent(items('[blurred]_-_For_each_collection'))}/docs"
            },
            "runAfter": {}
        }
    },
    "runAfter": {
        "[blurred]_-_Get_all_documents": [
            "Succeeded"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this on my side and works fine(both create and update operation).
1.There is no need to remove system property(such as '__rid') and delete document.
2.`x-ms-documentdb-raw-partitionkey` can work well.
Are all Partition key path of your collections `/MyPartitionKeyNumber`?

Comment: `PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header` this error causes by your Partition key value is not same with the value in your documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Upon further inspection, it appears most of my records are copied correctly between the databases. Some are failing, because the PartitionKey is `null` in the body, so an empty value in the header (which fails for obvious reasons and easy to fix). Some other documents fail for a reason I can't explain yet, but it's good to know the workflow works for 90% of the cases. Thanks for proofing me this block should just work.

Comment: You are welcome. If you would like, you could also choose Azure Data Factory to do such thing . Using it can be easier.

Comment: I've been creating several Logic Apps now which are copying data between several data repositories (SQL, Cosmos, blob, etc). Now looking at Data Factory and it looks like this service would have saved me a lot of work. I thought it only supported SQL, apparently I was wrong in this assumption. While DF isn't the answer to the question over here, I do think it's the service I should have been using instead of Logic Apps. Thanks!